# SQL wildcard match part of value

Tags: sql, sqlite

In a table I store the names of people and I wanted to use a wildcard to check if a part of students name is found. I tried using wild cards and this works if the condition value length is shorter than a value already in the database e.g

```
WHERE name LIKE '%Stu%'
```

And I have a person called 'Stuart', this will return a row, however if say I miss type the students name and it is longer than the stored i.e:

```
WHERE name LIKE '%Stuarfd%'
```

there I will get no results returned. Is there anyway to match only part of the string?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using SOUNDEX?

```
WHERE SOUNDEX(name) = SOUNDEX('Stuarf')
```

More info in:

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#soundex

Comment: if the SQLITE_SOUNDEX compile-time option is used when SQLite is built. Then it is the correct solution to the problem.

Comment: Just tried this and still no rows returned, is there something I need to enable in SQLITE before using these queries?

Comment: As pointed out in the first comment you need SQLLITE_SOUNDEX enabled at compile time https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#soundex

Answer (score 0):

What you might want is Levenshtein distance, which is also called edit distance.  This is the number of edits needed to change one string into another.

SQLite implements this through an extension called Spellfix1, which is available [here](https://www.sqlite.org/spellfix1.html).  The particular function is `spellfix1_editdist ()`.  Levenshtein distance is not really so useful for partial matches.  The idea is to be able to type in "Stuarf" and find "Stuart", because they are close.